# Actuators does not work

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-boot-actuator

I am trying to set up the actuator endpoints in my spring boot application, but I am not able to get the values I set up in my application.yml. This is my configuration so far:

```
src/main/resources/application.yml

info.app:
  description: mydescription
  name: myname
  version: 1.0

management.contextPath: /rest/internal/application
```

But, when I am trying to access to the endpoint I only get this:

```
rest call to http://localhost:8090/rest/internal/application/info

{
    "Manifest-Version":"1.0",
    "Created-By":"1.6.0_18 (Sun Microsystems Inc.)"
}
```

So, what can I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `.app` suffix is causing trouble, change the `info` section to i.e.

```
info:
  description: mydescription
  name: myname
  version: 1.0
```

[The documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/production-ready-endpoints.html#production-ready-application-info) states that:

> You can customize the data exposed by the info endpoint by setting
>   info.* Spring properties. All Environment properties under the info
>   key will be automatically exposed.

Here are the examples in the yaml:

```
info:
  app:
    name: MyService
    description: My awesome service
    version: 1.0.0
```